# Login Credentials are not working properly for Admins & Users

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a created a custom Login page for my project. I have given the roles as followed below

- `0` for SuperAdmin
- `1` For Admins
- `2` For Users

The problem is here that, The login works properly for `Super Admin` part. But when I create Admins and users and try to login with that credentials, it gives me error as **Invalid Username & password**. I tried checking and debugging it but don't know why it is not working.

Please see the code for the `Button_click` event for your reference:-

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        String LoginID = txtUsername.Text.Trim().ToLower();
        String LoginPassword = txtPassword.Text.Trim();

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultCSRConnection"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select username,password,usertype from tbl_User where username=@username and password=@password and active=@active", conn);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtUsername.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtPassword.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@active", 1);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            if (dt.Rows[0]["usertype"].ToString() == "0") //SuperAdmin
            {
                Session["User"] = dt.Rows[0]["username"].ToString();
                Response.Redirect("csrdashboards.aspx");
            }
            else if (dt.Rows[0]["usertype"].ToString() == "1") // Admin
            {
                Session["User"] = dt.Rows[0]["username"].ToString();
                Response.Redirect("csrdashboards.aspx");
            }
            else if (dt.Rows[0]["usertype"].ToString() == "2") // User
            {
                Session["User"] = dt.Rows[0]["username"].ToString();
                Response.Redirect("csrdashboards.aspx");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Invalid Username and Password')</script>");
        }
}
```

Please help. Do let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: are you getting dt null in case of admin and user?

Comment: @Neel: Yes I am getting `null` when I tried with Admin

Comment: @SonerGönül: It is getting saved as in encrypted format

Comment: it means entry of "1" and "2" are not stored in ur database please check ur database and see how many entries are there

Comment: @Neel: They are getting saved in the database, if you want I will show you.

Comment: and admin and users having active column as 1?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66997/discussion-between-rahul-sutar-and-neel).

Comment: sorry chat is not allowed in my company

Comment: ok, yes the active column is same for all the users and admins and also superadmins

Comment: @Neel: what to check, i didn't got u ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run query with same username and password in SQL server management studio and you will get the results and you will know if something is wrong with username and password. If no data is returned in SQL than your username or password should be incorrect. You are creating user with encrypted password and selecting user with plain password.Encrypt password before selecting user.

Comment: When I run with the password column with Encrypted code,it was returning me results. But when I was running with the text it is not returning anything, Why so

Comment: So your password is encrypted why are you sending plain text in query.

Comment: So how to send the password part ?

Comment: Encrypt password before sending.

Comment: How to do that, can you please tell ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66999/discussion-between-mairaj-ahmad-and-rahul-sutar).